# Are fields $Q[i\sqrt[4]{5}]$ and $Q[\sqrt[4]{5}]$ isomorphic?

Tags: field-theory

Are fields $Q[i\sqrt[4]{5}]$ and $Q[\sqrt[4]{5}]$ isomorphic?

I tried to prove they are not simiralry like one can show that $Q[i\sqrt{5}]$ and $Q[\sqrt{5}]$ are not isomorphic because if they were then $(f(i\sqrt{5})^2=f(-5)=-5$ but in $Q[\sqrt{5}]$ there is no element such that it's square is negative, but in my case this fourth degree root matches with powers of $i$ and I think I can't do anything similar.

Comment: Unlike $i\sqrt{5}$ and $\sqrt{5}$, which have different minimal polynomials over $\mathbb Q$ (i.e. $x^2+5$ vs. $x^2-5$), the elements $i\sqrt[4]{5}$ and $\sqrt[4]{5}$ have _the same_ minimal polynomial $x^4-5$ (which is minimal as it is irreducible over $\mathbb Q$ via Eisenstein's criterion).

Comment: so what? why is it helpful?

Comment: Any extension $\mathbb Q(\alpha)$ with algebraic $\alpha$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb Q[X]/(\mu_\alpha)$, where $\mu_\alpha$ is the minimal polynomial of $\alpha$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They are both isomorphic to the field $$\mathbb{Q}[X]/(X^4-5).$$ So, they are isomorphic. The basic idea is that, their minimal polynomials are the same, as pointed in comment.